# jquery: bind to node creation

Tags: jquery, binding

Is there a way to watch a document and bind an event when a node classed "media-modal" is dynamically added?

Incidentally, I don't have access to the code that triggers the node creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take back my comment, you can watch the `DOMNodeInserted` mutation event and run a reference against the class name of the element added.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    if(e.srcElement.className == 'media-modal'){
        alert(e.srcElement.className);
    }else{
        alert('not media-modal');   
    }
});
```

You could actually save a bit of performance by binding to the closest static parent element.

You can see a [working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/G4AmJ/)